# ":hover to change z-index" not working in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, hover, z-index

I have created a stack of div tags and used z-indexes to make them appear behind each other.

They overlap enough for them all to be visible and mouse-overable. I then assigned a :hover to change the z-index and make the div tag which is being hovered over come to the top of the pile.

An example of what I have would be...

CSS

```
#red-box {
position:fixed;
width:170px;
height:210px;
margin-left:70px;
top:40px;
background-color:red;
z-index:3;
}

#red-box:hover {
z-index:5;
}


#blue-box{
position:fixed;
width:170px;
height:210px;
margin-left:150px;
top:70px;
background-color:blue;
z-index:2;
}

#blue-box:hover{
z-index:5;
}
```

HTML

```
<a id="red-box"></a>
<a id="blue-box"></a>
```

I have also created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AhRst/) to help highlight what's going on.

This works great in the latest versions of all the browsers but the div tags' z-indexes do not change in IE8.

Could anyone help me fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This ought to fix it:
http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Basically, just set it to a ridiculously high number.

Edit: I just tested this in my version of IE on your JSFiddle, and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried giving them a ridiculously high z-index but that didn't work, I then created a parent div which they would be contained in and gave that an even higher z-index but that didn't work either. I've also tried different position: on all of the divs but that hasn't worked either. Could you perhaps link me to the jsFiddle you created so I can see what I have not done correctly?

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply earlier; I wasn't on my Windows box.
Unfortunately, now it seems to work without the silly numbers. I've checked and I'm definitely using IE8.
User Agent:
compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E

Comment: I just tested it with compatibility mode on, and then it failed to work in any way at all.